# Smooth scrolling to next class element jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, scroll

I want to prepare a smooth scrooling effect between titles using html and jQuery. By pressing button "next" the user is moved to the closest next title.

Simplifying my code looks like that:

```
<div class="article-content">
    <div class="title">
        <a href="#" id="next">next</a>
        <h2>Title1</h2>
    </div>        
       some text goes here        
    <div class="title">
        <a href="#" id="next">next</a>
        <h2>Title2</h2>
    </div>      
    <div class="title">
        <a href="#" id="next">next</a>
       <h2>Title3</h2>
    </div>      
</div>
```

I tried to use the jQuery code below, but it doesn't work:

```
$("#next").click(function() {
      var next;
      next = $(this).parent().next().find(".title");
       $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: next.offset().top
            }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: You can't have more than one element in the same page with the same id. You should use `data-id` or `class` to distinguish your "next" links.

Comment: There might be a conflict. Instead of using id, try assigning class to those buttons.

Comment: oh yes :) I've added class to the link, but it stll doesn't work :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/omarqa/dY44L/1/)

in html change id to class

```
<div class="title">
    <a href="#" class="next">next</a>
    <h2>title5</h2>
</div>
```

in javascript

```
$(".next").click(function() {
   $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop:$(this).parent().next().offset().top}, 'slow');});
```

---Update

you had a problem in your update which is that you used the

outside the div so the jquery can't get to it.

it should be like this

```
<div class="title">
<a href="#" class="next">next</a>
<h2>title1</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus mauris augue, molestie sit amet eros ac, tempus euismod justo. Donec faucibus sapien et lacus blandit sodales vitae vitae orci. Pellentesque aliquam suscipit purus. Fusce quis urna non arcu congue vulputate quis quis nunc. Praesent erat libero, porta eget lorem vitae, pretium sollicitudin felis. Pellentesque ultrices cursus lectus vel sodales. Fusce sodales ac dolor vel pretium. Nullam suscipit euismod nisi eu ullamcorper. Mauris consectetur urna accumsan nulla convallis, nec sagittis est faucibus. Nulla quis consectetur velit.
```

[update](http://jsfiddle.net/omarqa/Xf5nb/)

Comment: It works! Do you know how change it into "previous button"? Just by changing next() into prev()?

Comment: Yes it could work by just changing it to prev, but i recommend that you change the class name from Next into something else just for sack of consistency

Comment: I've updated your jsFiddle - [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/dY44L/3/) - file with some text and I noticed that it doesn't work properly now. Is there any option to fix it?

Comment: first you need to update you question with the issue so i can answer it and people won't have to go through comment, second it is really rude to unmark question because you want a new thing, you'll find the answer in the update in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version using:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".clicker", function() { 
// do things
});
```

and `previous` and `next` links with a bit of styling.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".clicker", function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this);

  if ($this.hasClass("next")) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      'scrollTop': $(this).closest(".container").next().offset().top
    }, 'slow');

  } else if ($this.hasClass("previous")) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      'scrollTop': $(this).closest(".container").prev().offset().top
    }, 'slow');
  }

});
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.container:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.container a {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.links {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <p>01. lorem ipsum </p>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="#" class="clicker next"> next </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <p>02. lorem ipsum </p>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="#" class="clicker previous"> previous </a> | <a href="#" class="clicker next"> next </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <p>03. lorem ipsum </p>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="#" class="clicker previous"> previous </a> | <a href="#" class="clicker next"> next </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <p>04. lorem ipsum </p>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="#" class="clicker previous"> previous </a> | <a href="#" class="clicker next"> next </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <p>05. lorem ipsum </p>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="#" class="clicker previous"> previous </a> | <a href="#" class="clicker next"> next </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <p>06. lorem ipsum </p>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="#" class="clicker previous"> previous </a> | <a href="#" class="clicker next"> next </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <p>07. lorem ipsum </p>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="#" class="clicker previous"> previous </a> | <a href="#" class="clicker next"> next </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <p>08. lorem ipsum </p>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="#" class="clicker previous"> previous </a> | <a href="#" class="clicker next"> next </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <p>09. lorem ipsum </p>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="#" class="clicker previous"> previous </a> | <a href="#" class="clicker next"> next </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <p>10. lorem ipsum </p>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="#" class="clicker previous"> previous </a> | <a href="#" class="clicker next"> next </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <p>11. lorem ipsum </p>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="#" class="clicker previous"> previous </a> | <a href="#" class="clicker next"> next </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <p>12. lorem ipsum </p>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="#" class="clicker previous"> previous </a> | <a href="#" class="clicker next"> next </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <p>13. lorem ipsum </p>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="#" class="clicker previous"> previous </a> | <a href="#" class="clicker next"> next </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <p>14. lorem ipsum </p>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="#" class="clicker previous"> previous </a> | <a href="#" class="clicker next"> next </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <p>15. lorem ipsum </p>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="#" class="clicker previous"> previous </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you

```
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(".title").offset().top}, 'slow');
```

Comment: thanks, but I need something, that work with 10 or more title elements. Your code works only when I have one link.

Comment: foreach link, you define a function like this `$("#link1").click(function(){ // code that scrolls });` and define other functions for link2 link3 ...

Comment: I know that I can do this in this way, but it's too much code, there must be shorter version. I found some code here [link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/find-next-div-with-a-certain-class-and-scroll-to) but it doesn't work on my webpage.

Answer (score 0):

To scroll smoothly to particulate div, use the below code:

```
$("a").on('click', function(e) {
  // prevent default anchor click behavior
  e.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
  }, 1000, function() {
    window.location.hash = this.hash;
  });
});
```

Also,please observed the newly added `id` for the title div and `href` location link in the below example demo.

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/J37L9/)**

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: is there any option to do that without adding 'id' for next title?